# How can I port this over to a different sandbox?

Tags: work.com

"I've build out the chatter badge function in my other dev environment

How can I port this over to a different sandbox?"

Comment: please be more descriptive while asking a question. what you want to done? what you have done so far and what issue you are facing? because your current statement it seems like you did some custom development which you want to migrate to sandbox and as answer I will reply that you can migrate using changeset. I might be wrong in context of your question so it is always better to be as descriptive as you can be.

Comment: this function is a part of work.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges you have built are not a part of configuration. This are records which you have created so, they cannot be transferred. 
You will have to import/create them in other environment. Batch information is saved in 'WorkBadge' and 'WorkBadgeDefinition' object. Try to import these records in other sandbox.

In addition, you will have to take care of badges image as well those may not work in target sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=badge_creating.htm&language=en_US), badges are not transferable from Sandbox to Production orgs.

However, you can take a look at API objects [WorkBadge](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workbadge.htm), [WorkBadgeDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workbadgedefinition.htm), [WorkBadgeDefinitionHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workbadgedefinitionhistory.htm) or [WorkBadgeDefinitionShare](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workbadgedefinitionshare.htm) and try to deploy them via [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) or [ANT migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool).